# Why does the PostgreSQL's Explain Analyze estimate the number of rows wrongly despite the correct stats?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-13

### Summary

I am joining a large table (~600K rows) with a smaller one (~11K rows) on a PostgreSQL database and I need to filter the result set by a descriptive `text` field.

When filtering by a `bigint` field of the smaller table the optimizer estimates the resulting number of rows correctly, but when filtering by a `text` field of the small table the optimizer underestimates the resulting number of rows by thousands of times, even though there's a 1-1 relation between the two.

I fail to understand this behavior.

The whole environment, including the data, can be setup with the instructions found in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/sHXew7G2). It is too large for conventional online mock DBs.

### Environment

```
select version();

|version                                                                                            |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|PostgreSQL 13.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0, 64-bit|
```

Sitting on Azure Flexible Server.

### Structures and data

**Parent** table (11228 rows):

```
create table parent_tb as
select id, md5(random()::text) descr
from generate_series(1::bigint,11228::bigint) as a(id);

alter table parent_tb add primary key (id);
create index idx_parent_tb_desc on parent_tb(descr);
```

Sample data:

```
select *
from parent_tb
limit 3;

|id |descr                           |
|---|--------------------------------|
|1  |a34ea09794a959c333116a83b3b77700|
|2  |6c40f8248d28dc541724e86d17f96775|
|3  |99f218398cd5125c803edf7eccc9c832|
```

---

**Child** table (597057 rows):

```
create table child_tb (
    id_tenant bigint,
    id bigint,
    descr text,
    id_ref bigint references parent_tb(id) null,
    primary key (id_tenant, id)
) partition by list(id_tenant);
```

The `child_tb` table is partitioned for every `id_tenant` value from `1` to `35`:

```
create table child_tb_ten_1 partition of child_tb for values in ('1');
-- ...
create table child_tb_ten_1 partition of child_tb for values in ('35');
```

Sample data:

```
select *
from child_tb
limit 3;

|id_tenant|id |descr                           |id_ref|
|---------|---|--------------------------------|------|
|1        |1  |638d2b2aa799d4871e0e2fa73ae607de|1     |
|1        |2  |f06668f8df7eaee3c539d2a1ba613604|1     |
|1        |3  |f588557239d37ec301bae79ab9a61742|1     |
```

### Collect data for test case

Collect statistics:

```
set default_statistics_target=10000;
vacuum analyze parent_tb;
vacuum analyze child_tb;
```

---

Pick a large `id_tenant`:

```
select count(1) n_keys, id_tenant, count(distinct id_ref) n_le, array_agg(distinct (id_ref,p.descr))
from child_tb c join parent_tb p on (c.id_ref=p.id)
group by id_tenant
order by 1 desc
limit 3;

|n_keys|id_tenant|n_le|array_agg                                 |
|------|---------|----|------------------------------------------|
|475759|6        |1   |{"(53,6ea8c6d951f3c8371662509ff8a5e37e)"} |
|18352 |14       |1   |{"(4,a0b360d0344c7018aa98d511392aa26f)"}  |
|17102 |2        |1   |{"(17,43595b7e1b092d120bbc8a94afca9583)"} |
```

Tenant `6` is clearly an outlier at a global level.

The statistics recognize that the first Most Common Values and Most Common Frequencies are related to tenant `6` which retains the ~80% of the data:

```
select
    (most_common_vals::text::numeric[])[1] mcv_1, (most_common_freqs::text::numeric[])[1] mcf_1,
    (most_common_vals::text::numeric[])[2] mcv_2, (most_common_freqs::text::numeric[])[2] mcf_2,
    *
from pg_stats where tablename in ('child_tb','child_tb_ten_6');

|mcv_1|mcf_1    |mcv_2|mcf_2      |schemaname|tablename     |attname  |
|-----|---------|-----|-----------|----------|--------------|---------|
|6    |0.7968402|14   |0.030737434|argodb    |child_tb      |id_tenant|
|     |         |     |           |argodb    |child_tb      |id       |
|     |         |     |           |argodb    |child_tb      |descr    |
|53   |0.7968402|4    |0.030737434|argodb    |child_tb      |id_ref   |
|6    |1        |     |           |argodb    |child_tb_ten_6|id_tenant|
|     |         |     |           |argodb    |child_tb_ten_6|id       |
|     |         |     |           |argodb    |child_tb_ten_6|descr    |
|53   |1        |     |           |argodb    |child_tb_ten_6|id_ref   |
```

---

Get the data from tenant `6` which will be used to filter the final query:

```
select distinct c.id_ref,p.descr
from child_tb c join parent_tb p on (c.id_ref=p.id)
where id_tenant=6;

|id_ref|descr                           |
|------|--------------------------------|
|53    |6ea8c6d951f3c8371662509ff8a5e37e|
```

### Behavior

**Please note:** every execution plan shown here is the result of an `explain analyze` and therefore represents the actual case.

**First attempt** — Access by Parent's ID.

Result OK — The optimizer correctly recognizes the number of rows resulting from the JOIN.

```
explain analyze
select * from child_tb c join parent_tb p on (c.id_ref=p.id)
where p.id=53 --fill with the appropriate value at point (1)
and c.id_tenant=6;

|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                       |
|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..17305.28 rows=475759 width=98) (actual time=0.025..88.812 rows=475759 loops=1)                          |
|  ->  Index Scan using parent_tb_pkey on parent_tb p  (cost=0.29..4.30 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=1 loops=1)|
|        Index Cond: (id = 53)                                                                                                    |
|  ->  Seq Scan on child_tb_ten_6 c  (cost=0.00..12543.38 rows=475759 width=57) (actual time=0.011..52.590 rows=475759 loops=1)   |
|        Filter: ((id_ref = 53) AND (id_tenant = 6))                                                                              |
|Planning Time: 0.183 ms                                                                                                          |
|Execution Time: 103.176 ms                                                                                                       |
```

---

**Second attempt** — Access by Parent's descriptive field.

Result KO — The optimizer underestimates the resulting records out of the join by 1000x!

```
explain analyze
select * from child_tb c join parent_tb p on (c.id_ref=p.id)
where p.descr='6ea8c6d951f3c8371662509ff8a5e37e' --fill with the appropriate value at point (1)
and c.id_tenant=6;

|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                       |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Gather  (cost=1004.32..9413.99 rows=42 width=98) (actual time=0.409..119.637 rows=475759 loops=1)                                                |
|  Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                             |
|  Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                            |
|  ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.32..8409.79 rows=18 width=98) (actual time=0.074..44.309 rows=158586 loops=3)                                           |
|        Hash Cond: (c.id_ref = p.id)                                                                                                             |
|        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on child_tb_ten_6 c  (cost=0.00..7884.91 rows=198233 width=57) (actual time=0.007..16.501 rows=158586 loops=3)     |
|              Filter: (id_tenant = 6)                                                                                                            |
|        ->  Hash  (cost=4.30..4.30 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=1 loops=3)                                                    |
|              Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                       |
|              ->  Index Scan using idx_parent_tb_desc on parent_tb p  (cost=0.29..4.30 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=1 loops=3)|
|                    Index Cond: (descr = '6ea8c6d951f3c8371662509ff8a5e37e'::text)                                                               |
|Planning Time: 0.620 ms                                                                                                                          |
|Execution Time: 134.484 ms                                                                                                                       |
```

---

**Additional attempt** — Obfuscate the Parent's accessing value with a materialized CTE.

The optimizer assumes a flat data distribution dividing the total number of rows of the Tenant `6` partition to the the global number of distinct `id_ref`s. This behavior is expected.

```
select 
(select count(1) from child_tb where id_tenant=6) cnt_child_6,
(select count(distinct id_ref) from child_tb) cnt_child_dist_refs,
(select count(1) from child_tb where id_tenant=6)/(select count(distinct id_ref) from child_tb) cnt_flat_6_distr

|cnt_child_6|cnt_child_dist_refs|cnt_flat_6_distr|
|-----------|-------------------|----------------|
|475759     |61                 |7799            |
```

Result OK — The optimizer correctly assumes the number of rows resulting from the JOIN.

```
explain analyze
with par as materialized (
    select * 
    from parent_tb
    where descr='6ea8c6d951f3c8371662509ff8a5e37e' --fill with the appropriate value at point (1)
)
select * from child_tb c join par p on (c.id_ref=p.id)
where c.id_tenant=6;

|QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                           |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Hash Join  (cost=4.33..13220.41 rows=7799 width=97) (actual time=0.031..124.799 rows=475759 loops=1)                                 |
|  Hash Cond: (c.id_ref = p.id)                                                                                                       |
|  CTE par                                                                                                                            |
|    ->  Index Scan using idx_parent_tb_desc on parent_tb  (cost=0.29..4.30 rows=1 width=41) (actual time=0.014..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)|
|          Index Cond: (descr = '6ea8c6d951f3c8371662509ff8a5e37e'::text)                                                             |
|  ->  Seq Scan on child_tb_ten_6 c  (cost=0.00..11353.99 rows=475759 width=57) (actual time=0.009..45.301 rows=475759 loops=1)       |
|        Filter: (id_tenant = 6)                                                                                                      |
|  ->  Hash  (cost=0.02..0.02 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)                                              |
|        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                 |
|        ->  CTE Scan on par p  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=40) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)                           |
|Planning Time: 0.150 ms                                                                                                              |
|Execution Time: 138.972 ms                                                                                                           |
```

### Conclusion

I fail to understand the `42` estimated rows by the optimizer in the **Second attempt**. I'd expect it to realize the 1-1 relation between the UK and the PK and use that one, like in the **First attempt**. Moreover, the `42` value looks arbitrary to me since I can't figure out from where it originates, unlike the `7799` estimate from the **Additional attempt**.

Comment: If one table has 50 times more rows than the other, how can they be 1-to-1?

Comment: @jjanes I was referring to the relation between the filter values, i.e. `parent_table.id=6` only exists for `parent_table.descr='6ea8c6d951f3c8371662509ff8a5e37e'` and vice-versa. If that's not clear enough in you opinion, I'll edit the question.